# How to float div up?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu and a submenu in different divs. There is a space between them. How can I make them look like a one whole menu? I used bootstrap navbar for main menu and simple nav for submenu.  I'm very newbie in css. this is what I have:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Website Logo</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">DashBoard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 250px;">
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LogOut</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Stats</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Api Calls</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foreigner92/eszf7/2/)
I just want to remove the space between them.

And one more little question:
how can I get rid of a little caret between button and it's dropdown? (white triangle between Account nav item and it's dropdown)

Comment: What @Kevin Bowersox said below. Plus, adding this to your CSS file should get rid of the little triangle: `.navbar .nav>li>.dropdown-menu:after { display: none !important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question can be answered by removing the default `margin-bottom` for the class navbar:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom:0
}
```

Now, for your second question. There is a triangle created using borders on your dropdown-menu. You can disable this with this css:

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: @oleg.foreigner Happy to help you out! You can accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS to remove the margins:

```
.navbar{
    margin:0px;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/eszf7/3/

Comment: The `.navbar` has a `margin-bottom` applied by the bootstrap.css